Can I install a 3-way smart dimmer switch and a wired companion dimmer here?
I purchased the following dimmer and dimmer companion.
Leviton Decora Smart - D26HD (Primary Dimmer)
Leviton Decora Smart - DD00R-DLZ (Companion Dimmer)
My house was built in 2009.  I have a three way switch and I would like to replace with the dimmers specified above.  When I watched the installation video (Instruction Video reference at 4:47) it showed 3 wiring configurations.  Where the 3rd configuration required an electrician to install.  Sadly my configuration is the 3rd configuration.
Is there anyway to install these dimmers in this configuration, or should I return them?  One other note, after testing the wires the hot wire is white and in the box with the two lines coming into it (Wall Box A In The Image Below).  I expected the hot wire to be black.
Picture of wire configuration:


The D26HD uses WiFi to communicate with other switches.  I would not use a WiFi companion switch on a staircase, a large room, or any other location where lighting control is critical.   It's fine to have WiFi so you can fiddle with colors and neat tricks from your phone.   But the light switch needs to work reliably and quickly.  Reliable wifi light switches are still a work in progress.   I suggest you get a main switch that uses ZWave, or perhaps not Leviton but Lutron and maybe others make multi-switch systems with their proprietary RF that is reliable enough.

@jay613 Actually, based on the instructions which (a) list many options for the primary control including WiFi, Z-Wave, Homekit, Zigbee and "Decora Digital" (presumably a proprietary protocol), and clear indication that the /3 gets redesignated as Hot/Neutral/Traveler, and that the primary is always last in the sequence (so it is the only one connecting to switched hot), and the companion switches (3-way/4-way) need neutral,

I'm about 99.9% certain that these switches use the traveler as a signal wire and the wireless (WiFi or any other) is for remote control/monitoring of the entire "system" and not for communication between the situations. In other words, no problem for use in a stairway or similar situation as the switch controls - both primary and companion - are physical.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact you are correct.   It's in Step 10.  I did not read that far.  I assumed, wrongly, the Companion uses the primary's native wireless.

I looked up D26HD on the Leviton site and the key words are right there: Neutral Wire Required.
You have a very common problem - switch boxes without neutral. With simple switches this doesn't matter. But smart switches have to get their power from somewhere, and the easiest to design/implement is to use neutral.
In fact, it is such a common problem that in 2011 the NEC started requiring neutral. But 2009 < 2011, and in fact many states are several years behind the latest NEC so even some houses built after 2011 may have switch boxes without neutral.
What you have is a switch loop. That brings hot and neutral to the light fixture box, connects neutral to the fixture and sends hot down to the switch with switched hot returning. Since cables come standard in black/white, it is OK to use white for hot or switched hot where normally it is neutral. However, to make it really obvious that white is not neutral, the white wire is used for hot, as you found. So your old switches were wired correctly for 2009.
Since you don't have neutral at the first of the 3-way switches, you don't have it at any of the 3-way switches. Which means you can't use this particular model of smart switch without running new cables - in this case replacing the black (switched hot)/white (hot) with black (hot)/red (switched hot)/white (neutral). And while it isn't hard for a homeowner to replace switches, running new cables can be a lot more work, which is why the manufacturer says "call an electrician".
Look for a switch that does what you want but that does not require a neutral. There are some alternatives:

Batteries - But then that means battery replacements. But actually there are quite a few smart switch "remotes" that just have to send a very low-power radio signal when you flip the switch that last several years on a battery. But for the "main" switch, particularly if you want things like WiFi, batteries don't work as well.
Leak current through the light - This works really well with incandescent bulbs. But it doesn't work as well with LEDs because they often glow or flash with just a little bit of current.
Ground instead of neutral - This is allowed but only with very low power usage.
No constant current needed - This can be done for some types of smart switches but is particularly limiting for things like WiFi that need to be powered on all the time.


If you want to stick with Leviton for some reason, they make a no-neutral smart dimmer.    It requires a separate Leviton "Wifi Bridge", a little widget the plugs into a wall outlet and handles the power-hungry aspects of things.  And for the far-end switch, a Leviton "Anywhere" Companion, which looks like a wall switch but uses batteries.   It would go in Box B (or anywhere) but not connect to the wires.   If you're going this route you should also compare with switching entirely to Hue, Cync, etc starting with smart fixtures or bulbs.

Yes, the battery powered companion is a no go.  Thank you for the information.
